# How to sort headings alphabetically in a .md file in Docusaurus

Tags: docusaurus

I have a markdown file in the `docs` folder in my docusaurus project.

I have H2 and H3 headings in that markdown file that i wish to be sorted alphabetically when it is rendered.

How can i achieve this functionality?